# How to install wxpython for Linux

Tags: linux, wxpython

I need this package for a project, but i am unable to install it.
My python version is 3.10.12, and i use Ubuntu.
I have tried 4 different pip install usages, but none of them worked.

Comment: This the goto site for wxPython installation [https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html](https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html). If necessary, build on another system and copy over the relevant files. Saved my bacon ore than once :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using: `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0-dev` in your terminal